# how to move a wordpress blog to my static site

Tags: migration

I am sorry in advance for the noob question. I am just looking for direction. I have read the codex and scoured this site for help and cannot find anything useful.

Here's the situation. My client has an old wordpress site. I am building her a new HTML5 site but want to carry her old blog posts and comment structure over.

So right now I have www.testsite.com which is her wordpress site and the only part I want to take is /blog. I have my new site under testsite.com/new and the new wp installation under testsite.com/new/blog

If this makes sense to anyone can you think of the best way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you built a new theme for the WordPress site or are you talking about a completely new site that is not WordPress but needs to have WordPress' posts?

Comment: Do you want to move the WordPress site to /blog and set your new HTML5 site to be www.testsite.com? Please let me know if I understand the question correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The main WordPress-specific solution would be to export the site content as XML (Dashboard -> Tools -> Export -> All Content), then do with the XML file whatever you need/want.

Comment: The end result I am looking for is a static site with their old wp blog at newsite/blog... which is the only wp part of the new site...just their old blog.

Answer (score 0):

If the blog doesn't have many posts, then you can copy the style.css along with the blog's HTML page by page. If it does have many posts, make a PHP scripts that gets all the posts URLs and then use cURL or an alternative to copy their HTML and write them to HTML files. If you want to change the theme too, then retrieve the posts from the database and write them as HTML files, along with your new design's HTML. If you want instruction on how to do this, I can offer some examples.